# How to extract parameter value in Apache httpd.conf in Location tag?

Tags: regex, apache, httpd.conf, contextpath

I'm looking to access the parameters of a URL in the `<Location>` tag in Apache's httpd.conf file

The actual URL looks like this: `https://website.com:1111/track?p=admin&s=875`

I have the following code and 2 parameters in `httpd.conf` file

```
<Location "/tracker/track?p=&s=">
  ProxyPass "http://website.com:1111/track?p=&s="
  ProxyPassReverse "http://website.com:1111/track?p=&s="
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

I'm not sure what to put in front of the `=` so that any value that comes in, gets passed on. Will a regex work here?

Comment: You can write a regex something like https?.*p=(\w+)&s=(\d+) and capture group1 and group2 content

Comment: @Pushpesh how do I capture the content, can yo give me an example?

Comment: Do you have more links on the file? or something similar which access the same parameters?
Example here: https://regex101.com/r/xyA1f5/1/, group 1 and group 2 contains which you need.

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri: What language/script you are using? You will need to write some code using regex and will get the expected output.

Comment: @lucas_7_94 the regex will only solve the pattern problem. my main concern is how do the values get passed in the location tag i. e. To the `proxpass`, do I put the regex there also and it automatically takes the param values?